# Auto Layout Issues: Prevents Image from loading?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around auto layout. I just can't get it to work right. Just when I thought I had it right (everything looked OK in Preview), my imageview stopped loading! What's the best approach here for Auto Layout? What steps should I take with the following UI? I deleted all of the constraints so that I can start over:

[image: Storyboard Preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are not giving the (x,y) of the image, that means the specific position where you want the image to be situated with respect to its superview. Try adding leading and top constraints from the pin tab situated below the storyboard. After giving (x,y) also add width and height of the image according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This really helped me out. I'm still figuring things out, but doing what you said got me on the right track. I found that I got better results if I unchecked "constrain to margins". Any idea why this is like this?

Comment: in storyboard basically a default margin is already given, by disabling the "constraints to margin", you actually set the margin value to 0 and then the constraints which you set are applied to actual device margin.

Answer (score 0):

With autolayout it's important to get rid of all the errors. Give everything enough constraints to determine its position and size. With UIImages I like to give them constant heights and width Constraints in Interface Builder, make Outlets for each of them, wait for the image to download, and then update the constraints' constants. That way to get programmatically set the image size and keep all the convince of autolayout. Keep in mind if you want the child to grow the parent then you have to give it a higher content hugging priority. If you are getting runtime warnings reduce the priority on the least important constraint.